# Hypothesis Test on variance in regression

Tags: regression, variance, hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

In an exercise I have the output of R for a simple linear regression that displays

> Residual standard error: 0.1011 on 23 degrees of freedom

And I have to do the following hypothesis test:
$$H_0: \sigma^2=0.01\text{ vs }H_1: \sigma^2\ne 0.01$$ with a significativity of $1-\gamma=0.1$

So I did this:

Assuming that $SS_E=\text{Sum of Squared Errors}=\sum (y-\hat{y})^2$

Assuming that $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{SS_E}{n-2}$ so $SS_E=(n-2)\hat{\sigma}^2$

We can write
$$\frac{SS_E}{\sigma^2}=\frac{(n-2)\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-2}$$

So, for the test, I get an acceptation region of
$$\chi^2_{n-2}\left(\frac{1-\gamma}{2}\right)\le\frac{(n-2)\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}\le\chi^2_{n-2}\left(\frac{1+\gamma}{2}\right)$$

And, due to the fact that $\frac{(n-2)\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{23\cdot(0.1011)^2}{0.01}\approx23.509$ this converts to
$$\chi^2_{23}\left(0.05\right)=13.091\le 23.509 \le 35.172=\chi^2_{23}\left(0.95\right)$$

So we should reject the alternative hypothesis.

What's throwing me off is a note on this exercise that suggest

> It may be useful to know that 1.714 is the 0.95-quantile of $t_{23}$

And I really can't understand where the t-Student should fit in here. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the sample variance of the $y$s in your data, i.e., the $SST/(n-1)$?

Comment: I don't have the raw data, only the output from R. I guess I can calculate $SST$ if needed, but why should I do that?

Comment: It is probably irrelevant. It seems like a mistake. My conjecture was that maybe the unconditioned variance of $Y$ is $0.01$, then checking whether after conditioning on $X$ is lower than that is equivalent to checking the significance of the slope term (thus the $t$ distribution).